# Convert Comma seperated javascript object value to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Javascript Object:

```
 Object { dsfc@df.com=80,  psfedd@dc.com=119,  ifdsiw@nh.com=240}
```

I want to convert this Object as an Array Like:

```
[{ "dsfc@df.com"="80"}, {"psfedd@dc.com"="119"}, {"ifdsiw@nh.com"="240"}]
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: strange object ... show your object in its code representation

Comment: i converted hashmap<Strnig,Integer> into JSON response using JSOn Api.

Comment: i suppose you are using Java with Hashmap,JSONArray, JSONObject classes

Comment: Yes @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map properties of your object to an array (using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)):

```
var obj = {
    'debbiec@example.com': 80,
    'paleredd@example.com': 119,
    'itdiw@example.com': 240
};

var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    var arrItem = {};
    arrItem[key] = String(obj[key]);
    return arrItem;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: PLease check my edits above , i want separate objects